# How to call a method in dependency module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning Angular. How can I call a method in a dependency module?

app.js

```
(function(){
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['map']);
    myApp.filter('move', function(){
        return function(name){
            return walk(name);
        } 
    });
})();
```

map.js

```
(function(){
    var mapMod = angular.module('map',[]);

    mapMod.factory('walk', function(){
        return "walking...";
    });

})();
```

After loading an html page with app.js and map.js included in scripts,

```
 ReferenceError: walk is not defined
```

How can I call walk in move filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you almost got it right, you need to inject `walk` in the filter, you can opt any mode of [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) via explicit annotation using array syntax(in the example below), using $inject syntax or implicit dependency annotation (with ng-annotate for safe minification). Since you have listed `map` as dependency for your module `myApp`, all the entities registered in `map` module will be available in `myApp` as well. Also you may want to refer to the documentation on [how to write a factory/service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

```
(function() {
  var mapMod = angular.module('map', []);

  mapMod.factory('walk', function() {
    return function(name) {
      return "walking..." + name;
    }
  });

})();
(function() {
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['map']);
  myApp.filter('move', ['walk',
    function(walk) {
      return function(name) {
        return walk(name);
      }
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```js
(function() {
  var mapMod = angular.module('map', []);

  mapMod.factory('walk', function() {
    return function(name) {
      return "walking..." + name;
    }
  });

})();
(function() {
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['map']);
  myApp.filter('move', ['walk',
    function(walk) {
      return function(name) {
        return walk(name);
      }
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div>{{"test"|move}}</div>
</div>
```